# Find all the minimum edge cuts of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

An edge cut of a graph g is a set of edges whose deletion from g disconnects g. In *Mathematica*, we can use the function [`FindEdgeCut`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindEdgeCut.html) to find a minimum  edge cut of a graph, but not all. For example.

```
g=Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {UndirectedEdge[1, 2], UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 4], UndirectedEdge[1, 5], UndirectedEdge[5, 6], UndirectedEdge[6, 4], UndirectedEdge[2, 5], 
UndirectedEdge[3, 6]}, {FormatType -> TraditionalForm, GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Thick"}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], ImagePadding -> 0, VertexLabels -> 
{Placed["Name", Center]}, VertexSize -> {0.4}, VertexStyle -> {GrayLevel[1]}}]

FindEdgeCut[g]
HighlightGraph[g, %]
```

[image]

Clearly, $\{(12),(15)\}$, $\{(34),(46)\}$ are also minimum edge cuts, respectively.

---

Edits: my graph is as following.

```
ImportString["O~tIID@wL~j`PbOqgLJ@p", "Graph6"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

g = Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {UndirectedEdge[1, 2], 
    UndirectedEdge[2, 3], UndirectedEdge[3, 4], UndirectedEdge[1, 5], 
    UndirectedEdge[5, 6], UndirectedEdge[6, 4], UndirectedEdge[2, 5], 
    UndirectedEdge[3, 6]}, {FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
    GraphHighlightStyle -> {"Thick"}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]], 
    ImagePadding -> 0, VertexLabels -> {Placed["Name", Center]}, 
    VertexSize -> {0.4}, VertexStyle -> {GrayLevel[1]}}];

ec = FindEdgeCut[g, ##] & @@@ {{1, 5}, {5, 6}, {4, 6}};

Column[HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ ec]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To avoid specifically identifying the nodes

```
ec = GatherBy[
     DeleteDuplicates[
      FindEdgeCut[g, ##] & @@@ 
       Subsets[VertexList[g], {2}]], 
     Length][[1]];

Column[HighlightGraph[g, #] & /@ ec]
```

< same graphs >

**EDIT 2:** For more complicated graphs

```
g = CycleGraph[8, VertexLabels -> Automatic];

Partition[
  HighlightGraph[g, #,
     GraphHighlightStyle -> "Dashed"] & /@
   Select[
    Subsets[EdgeList[g],
     {EdgeConnectivity@g} (* min # edges to cut *)
      (* all combos of req'd # edges *)],
    ! ConnectedGraphQ@EdgeDelete[g, #] & 
    (* eliminate any still connected graphs *)],
  UpTo[5]] //
 Grid
```

[image]

Comment: An interesting question is: The function `FindEdgeCut(g,a,b)` also only  finds a smallest (a,b)-edge cut of g.(**not all**), how to prove that the above codes found all the minimum cuts of `g`. Is there an  smallest edge cut of g missing?

Comment: For example, `g = CycleGraph[8, VertexLabels -> Automatic]; ec = GatherBy[
  DeleteDuplicates[FindEdgeCut[g, ##] & @@@ Subsets[VertexList[g], {2}]], 
   Length][[1]]`. Clearly, the edge set $\{ (45) , (78)\}$ is  a minimum edge cut, but your codes **have missed it**.

Comment: See Edit 2 for more complicated graphs

Comment: Thank you very much. However, due to memory constraints, could we **not** generate the selected subset of a graph at once? I have the graph in the end of post. Its edge connectivity is 6, we shall first use Subsets to store 32468436 edge-subsets (every subset has 6 members) . The memory's cost seems high. (By the way, it looks like it took a lot of time.)